# How to replace deprecated CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue with CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey

Tags: extension

I am trying to fix problems in an extension that relies on the deprecated (now removed) `CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue` but am unsure of the details of the new code.

The Developed Docs give useful details of the suggested replacement, e.g. (`CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey('CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution', 'contribution_status', 'Completed')`): https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/pseudoconstant/

- How do I identify the relevant BAO name for this, however?
- And what is the appropriate replacement for `CRM_Core_OptionGroup::values('from_email_address', NULL, NULL, NULL);`?

Is there any developer documentation about how to replace deprecated methods in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can use API4 to fetch the Options or value of the option

```
$optionValue = \Civi\Api4\OptionValue::get()
  ->addSelect('value')
  ->addWhere('name', '=', 'Completed')
  ->addWhere('option_group_id:name', '=', 'contribution_status')
  ->execute()
  ->first()['value'];
```